# Appending Characters but Asset Library doesn't load

Tags: append, asset-browser

[image: Screenshot 1, Character in original file with poses saved in the Asset browser]

I have created my characters, made my shape keys, created a pose library and saved everything in the asset browser as illustrated in the picture attached **(Screenshot 1).**, However, everytime i append the file into another scene, the poses of the characters are never imported to the new file, what am i doing wrong? **(See screenshot 2)**

[image: Example 2, the character appended into new scene but the poses did not load as well,]

Comment: Hello ! What exactly are you appending to the other file ? If you append only the character, I'm not sure the action poses are also appended with it

Comment: to see the poses of the library you need to select it. In the second screenshot, you still have "Current File" selected.